# Call Phalcon TaskAction from Controller

Tags: php, controller, command-line-interface, phalcon

Is that possible to call a taskAction (which is in cli Task) from any Controller in Phalcon?

I have a app->task->mainTask.php and app->controller->apiController.php
I want to call a function which is in mainTask.php from apiController.php, Can I do that? if yes, How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it easier to just move this code from task to service and use this service in both controller and task?